# Bash alias with an argument that works with pipe and globs

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, command-line-arguments, alias

I have a convenience function in my bashrc file that looks like following:

```
function get_pattern()
{
    grep "P1" $1 | grep -v "BUT_NOT_THIS" | awk -F":" '{print $(1)}' | sort -u
}

alias gp='get_pattern'
```

This works fine if I run it on individual file like `gp file_1.c`. However I am unable to run it like `find . -name "*.c" -type f | xargs gp`. I also fail to run it like `gp *.c`. How do I code get_pattern so that I can have all these conveniences.

NOTE: I have simplified the function for easier understanding. Not expecting smart grep/awk/sed/sort hacks or tweaks. The question is I have an alias that takes filenames as arguments. Want it to work with pipes, and preferably with globs.

Comment: Using an alias with a function is an anti-pattern! Just use the function alone and pass arguments to it

Comment: Using an alias is an anti-pattern!

Comment: Shell aliases are best used as command line shortcuts for interactive use, just to save typing time.  They are ill-suited for scripting.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by the experts, aliases are not suited for your requirement.

In your function, you are only passing the first argument to grep, as in `grep "P1" $1`.  Change it to use all arguments, this way:

```
function get_pattern() {
    grep "P1" "$@" | grep -v "BUT_NOT_THIS" | awk -F":" '{print $(1)}' | sort -u
}
```

Note:

- When you invoke your function as `get_pattern *.c` and there are matching files, the function doesn't see `*.c`, it sees the list of matching files.  The glob expansion is done by the shell while invoking the function, but not inside the function.
- In the present format, the function doesn't read from stdin.  So, piping the results of another command into your function may not work.  To make it accept stdin, you need to change the first grep to:

  `grep "P1" - "$@"`

That would mess up the invocation when you intend the function to only read the files.  So, it would be better to rewrite the function this way:

```
function get_pattern() {
    if (($# > 0)); then
        # arguments passed, use them as file names to grep from
        grep_args=("$@")
    else
        # no arguments passed, grep from stdin
        grep_args=(-)
    fi
    grep "P1" "${grep_args[@]}" | grep -v "BUT_NOT_THIS" | awk -F":" '{print $(1)}' | sort -u

}
```

Comment: Using `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` on `Linux centos72_base 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64`. Thanks for elaborate reply. `"$@"` enables me to use glob. But your second part of solution (stdin) is not working for me. I still can't use `echo "file1.c" | gp` or `find . -name "*.c" -type f | xargs gp`

Comment: You can't use the alias with xargs or pipe, as pointed out by @williampursell.  Do an `export -f get_pattern` of your function and use the function name itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to focus on the issue of piping data to xargs.  That doesn't work because xargs doesn't know anything about the alias.  However you can effectively pass the function definition in to make it work (non-portable solution which works in bash and possibly some other shells, but don't expect it to work everywhere) with `export -f`:

```
$ foo() { echo foo: $@; }
$ echo bar baz | xargs bash -c 'foo $@' _
_: foo: command not found
$ export -f foo
$ echo bar baz | xargs bash -c 'foo $@' _
foo: bar baz
```

I am not aware of any way to do this with an alias, but I'm also not aware of any reason to ever use an alias.  Stop using aliases.

Comment: You mean `bash -c 'foo "$@"'` (with the double quotes), right?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I'm actually not sure.  In this case, the word splitting is going to be normalized by xargs, and I think there's really no way to sanely handle whitespace with this setup.  `"$@"` would probably give a false sense of security.

Comment: Hmm. A fair point -- though `xargs` *can* be used safely, if leveraging GNU extensions -- if one used `-d $'\n'` or `-0`, for example -- in which case the `bash` invocation would be the weak point.